# Prevent sql update on existing Rails model when appending to has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

According to the present Rails documentation, regarding the `<<` operator on a has_many relationship on an **existing object**:

```
collection<<(object, …)

Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys
to the collection’s primary key.
```

***(This is the interesting bit)***

```
Note that this operation instantly fires update sql without waiting for 
the save or update call on the parent object.
```

I didn't realize this would happen, I was quite surprised; I could have sworn this was not the case in the past, though I admit I could be wrong.

In either case, I haven't been able to find any additional documentation regarding this, however I wonder if there is a way to prevent this update?

My situation is simple, I merely have an object which exists in the database, which is being prepared for an "edit" page. I append one or multiple related objects before the page is render. C'est tout.

**Update**:
Apparently the same update-scenario also occurs if you set the has_many relationship directly from an array using the `=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collection's `build` method. That won't immediately fire a SQL statement like the others do.

```
foo.bars.build(attributes)
foo.save
```

Lots of good information can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Note: This method assumes you have the flexibility to create your objects through the build method rather than using `Bar.new`.

Comment: Ok cool, I've never used that method, but very good to know. Unfortunately, I do need to associate an existing object. I ended up solving the problem by slightly modifying the system to allow this auto-update scenario. Thanks for your answer.